# How to use a block particle in /particles?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

version: 1.14.4
java edition

I tried:`/particle block` and `/execute at @p run particle minecraft:block`, but it didn't work so I tried to find any answers online, but still I couldn't find someone having a same issue. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/particle block <block> <position> <delta> <speed> <count> <normal|force>` command is for the particle effects for when you mine the block, run on the block, etc.. You need to specify a block for it to work. For e.g.;

```
/particle block gravel ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0
```

This'll create a **gravel** block effect right under your feet. (it is recommended to leave delta 0 0 0)

```
/particle block glowstone ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0
```

This'll create a **glowstone** block effect right under your feet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're welcome!