# How can I create different portals to different sky block islands for multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I downloaded a sky block datapack and I want to create different portals to different sky block island for multiplayer.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What datapack did you download?

Answer (score 2):

### Best Solution

From they way you posed the question it sounded like you intended to use minecraft's built-in portals, particularly the nether portal, impossible to do without a mod or script. (which you should provide more information about)  
  
 However the best, most well rounded solution I can come up with is a teleportation pad using a "special" block. The command for that would look something like this.

#### The command:

`execute at @e[distance=..3] if block ~ ~-1 ~ ^your block^ at @s as @s run tp @e[distance=..3,limit=1] ^coordinates^ ^rotational coordinates^`

- ^your block^ is where players(and all entities including items and pantings) are teleported from, it should never show up anywhere else in the map.
- ^coordinates^ where you want to teleport to. Your current coordinates (x, y, z) can be found by pressing `Fn+F3` and looking for `Block: "some numbers/coordinates"`.
- ^rotational coordinates^ these are 2 more coordinates that determine the direction your looking, these can be found by looking 2 rows under your coordinates.

  By placing this command in a "repeating" command block set to "always active" right next to or under ^your block^, players will be teleported to ^coordinates^. From the side would look like...

---

- □=Air
- ▅=Block
- ▣=Command Block
- ⊞=Portal Stone

  ▅ ▅ ⊞ ⊞ ⊞ ▅ ▅
  ▅ ▅ ▅ ▣ ▅ ▅ ▅
  Or like this..
  □ □ □ □ □ □ ▣ □
  ▅ ▅ ⊞ ⊞ ⊞ ▅ ▅
   Or this..
  ▅ ▅ ⊞ ⊞ ⊞ ▣ ▅
  ▅ ▅ ▅ ▅ ▅ ▅ ▅

---

To add some flare to the teleport, add a similar command block with an identical command but instead of `run tp` type `run particle`. For the sake of being concise, I will link to [another forum post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/357946/how-to-use-a-block-particle-in-particles) that explains how to finish the command.

How can I improve on this answer?
If it was helpful mark it correct so people visiting this page know.